# ps1 funcionando bien en ISE y no en consola powershell ni en tarea programada

Tags: script, powershell

me estoy volviendo un poco loco ya. Tengo un script ps1 que funciona perfectamente en powershell ISE pero cuando le digo directamente ejecutar con powershell o desde una tarea programada se ejecuta una sola vez y se cierra (he programa a colocar los parámetro -noexit en la tarea programada). El código es el siguiente:

```
$MonitorFolder = "\\sharedfolder"
$MonitorStopFile = "monitor.die"
$smtpServer = "xxx"
$smtpFrom = "xxx"
$smtpTo = "xxx"
#$smtpSubject = "Asignacion tarea LDA"
$smtpSubject = "Asignacion tarea LDA $($MonitorFolder)."
$smtpPort = "25"

$mailparam =@{
    To = $smtpTo
    From = $smtpFrom
    Subject = $smtpSubject
    Body = $smtpBody
    SmtpServer = $smtpServer
    Port = $smtpPort
    #Credential = $smtpCred
}

$SourceID = "MonitorFiles"
$IncomingFiles = Get-ChildItem $MonitorFolder

$smtp = New-Object -TypeName "Net.Mail.SmtpClient" -ArgumentList $smtpServer

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $MonitorFolder
#Files only. Default is files + directory
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'

$newFileSubscription = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier NewFileCreated -Action { 
Write-Host "New file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)"

$smtpBody += "`n[$(Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss)]`tNew file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)"

if($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name -eq $MonitorStopFile) {
    Write-Host "Monitoring stopped"
    #Stop monitoring
    Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $newFileSubscription.Id
    #Dispose FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Dispose()
}
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom, $smtpTo, $smtpSubject, $smtpBody)      
}
```

Agradecería muchísimo la ayuda :)

Comment: Lo he ejecutado en ISE e igualmente se ejecuta una única vez... Una consulta, ¿Donde defines la variable $Event?

Comment: Hola Victor, gracias por tu respuesta. A mí sí me funciona correctamente si ejecuto este codigo tal cual en ISE. Respecto a la variable que indicas no tengo más código que este... ¿me falta algo para que funcione bien? Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Carlos, tu idea es que se ejecute varias veces? o que funcione como un trigger que se dispara cuando se realiza el cambio? Porque realmente no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo correr de forma correcta. Si te parece, te pido que grabes una demo de como te funciona correctamente con la siguiente aplicación (te genera un GIF): http://gifrecorder.com/